"Site health Status" will intermittantly show an issue on the Dashboard, but when I look at site health, it says everything is "running smoothly"
So I'm wondering, is there a way to log issues that intermittently occur in Site Health that I can look at later?
This is a production server on a VPS running nginx, and from what I can tell, my VPS "neighbors" don't seem to be pushing it into performance hits (although I have considered that maybe this is the source for the intermittent issue).
Thanks in advance for any thoughts or comments!
